# Android apk keeps crasing , probably issue with the manifest, please have a look

Tags: android, xml

I have no idea what can be wrong, maybe you are able to spot it  i spend the last hour trying to fix it and the app just keeps crashing on start-up, dont really understand why is that. Thanks in advance!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.miniproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

          <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".splashScreen">   
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.miniproject.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

          <activity 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".tableScreen">
         </activity>




    </application>

</manifest>
```

Log:

```
p.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:492)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5948)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6117)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:615)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:559)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:56)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:480)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at com.example.miniproject.splashScreen.onCreate(splashScreen.java:17)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     ... 11 more
11-16 23:20:04.693: D/dalvikvm(1323): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 473K, 17% free 2712K/3268K, paused 60ms, total 60ms
11-16 23:20:07.973: I/Process(1323): Sending signal. PID: 1323 SIG: 9
11-16 23:20:04.563: W/dalvikvm(1323): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a6fb90)
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323): Process: com.example.miniproject, PID: 1323
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.miniproject/com.example.miniproject.splashScreen}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
11-16 23:20:04.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.ap
```

Comment: Just a wild guess as you have not provided a log cat trace, but I noticed that you main launcher activity is ".splashScreen".   Did you mean ".SplashScree" with a capital "S"?

Comment: Hello, thanks for interest.The files i have are MainActivity.java ,splashScreen.java tableScreen.java, active_main.xml,splash.xml,table.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says it plainly "Binary XML file line #1: You must supply a layout_width attribute". So, on one (or more) of your XML layouts, it doesn't have a layout_width attribute. So check your XMLs and make sure all the layouts have one.

Comment: Works like a charm. I added layout_width to splash.xml and it stopped crashing. Thank You kindly.

Answer (score 1):

From this line: "Binary XML file line #1: You must supply a layout_width attribute", I suppose the parent view of your .xml file did not indicate its width.

It should be like this:

// The parent layout, LinearLayout, or whatever the parent layout is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <!- Blah blah-->
</LinearLayout>
```